# Is it required to keep the virtual machine window open to keep it running in Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, unattended

Using Windows XP as host and guest(s) and VirtualBox as virtualization solution.

Do I have to keep the guest's window open in order to keep it running?

When I try to close it, the "Close Virtual Machine" popup comes up.

If not possible, how can I reduce the overhead caused by keeping the windows open?

It's nice in VmWare Server 1 and 2 that you can keep the instances running without keeping the guest windows open.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is to start the VM using vboxheadless.

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm <uuid|name>
```

The only problem of doing this from command line is that the process become the child process for the command prompt windows. So you will need to put it in a bat file to get it behave like a "background" process in Unix.

Comment: Can you not do `start vbxoheadless...` to make it run as a separate process?

Comment: You can do that even with "start /B vboxheadless ....." but once you kill the command prompt, it will kill the vm with it. I believe there is a ticket asking vbox developer to make vboxheadless fork to a different process in windows.

Answer (score 1):

The VirtualBox help file describes how to do what you want. In VBox v3.06, it's listed in: 
[Chapter 7. Alternative front-ends; remote virtual machines](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#id2515779)

Comment: Gotta love RTFM answers. :)

Comment: True, but if the answer to everything was "RTFM" then that would make SF a fairly useless website

Comment: Sometimes finding the right manual / part of the manual is the challenge :)